# outDir and outFile for multiple directories

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc

I have this project structure

```
node_modules
tsconfig.json
resources
src/
 server/
  anyFolder1/
   anyFile.ts
  anyFolder2/
   anyFile.ts
  index.ts

 client/
  anyFolder1/
   anyFile.ts
  anyFolder2/
   anyFile.ts
  index.ts

 shared/
  anyFolder1/
   anyFile.ts
  anyFolder2/
   anyFile.ts
  index.ts
```

And in tsconfig.json

```
{
 "include": [
  "src/client/**/*",
  "src/server/**/*",
  "src/shared/**/*",
 ],
 "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./resources",
 }
}
```

after compiling I get

```
resources/
 server/
  anyFolder1/
   anyFile.js
  anyFolder2/
   anyFile.js
  index.js

 client/
  anyFolder1/
   anyFile.js
  anyFolder2/
   anyFile.js
  index.js

 shared/
  anyFolder1/
   anyFile.js
  anyFolder2/
   anyFile.js
  index.js
```

But I want it to be like this

```
resources/
 server/
  build.js

 client/
  build.js

 shared/
  build.js
```

To compile everything from a specific folder into one file of the same folder

What is the best way for me to do this? I would like for the whole project to have the same compilation rules lying in 1 file and the final structure was exactly the same as I showed, while it is desirable that this works only for selected directories inside my src without reacting to other folders and files.